# tkinter の bad geometry specifier "200*100" というエラーの意味がよくわからない

Tags: python, python3, tkinter

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このプログラムを実行しようとすると
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

というメッセージが表示されます。
何が悪いのかよくわからないので一度Pythonをアンインストールして最新のPythonを再インストールしたのですが結果は変わりませんでした。
インストールする前のPathのチェック欄にはチェックを入れました。
すごく初歩的なことで恐縮ですが、お願いします。

Comment: コードやエラーメッセージはスクリーンショットでなく、テキストとして質問に貼り付けて下さい。それにより検索なども可能になりますし、特定の色合いが苦手な方でも読めるようになります。その際、貼り付けたコードなどは[選択した上で `{}` ボタンをクリック](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2069/3054)して整形済みブロックにすると、インデントが保持され、`<` などの文字もそのまま使えるようになります。

Comment: もし画像を貼る場合でも、デスクトップを丸々ではなく必要最小限の領域にトリミング(切り抜き)することを意識されると、見る人にとって親切かなと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`200*100`ではなく、`200x100`ではないですかね。

Answer (score 3):

`tkinter` の使い方は独特な所があり、色々とつまずくかも知れません。

使い方が解らないメソッドなどは `help` 関数などで説明を読むことができます。今回ですと、Pythonコード内で `help(root.geometry)` とすると、

```
Help on method wm_geometry in module tkinter:

wm_geometry(newGeometry=None) method of tkinter.Tk instance
    Set geometry to NEWGEOMETRY of the form =widthxheight+x+y. Return
    current value if None is given.
```

と出てきますので、`widthxheight+x+y` という形式が期待されているのだなと解ります。
（`+x+y` の部分は位置の指定で、省略可能です）

公式ドキュメントにも多少は説明がありますので関連しそうな記述を探して見るのも手です。

> `geometry`
>    これは `widthxheight` 形式の文字列です。ここでは、ほとんどのウィジェットに対して幅と高さピクセル単位で (テキストを表示するウィジェットに対しては文字単位で)表されます。例えば: `fred["geometry"] = "200x100"` 。
>   —— https://docs.python.jp/3/library/tkinter.html

Answer (score 1):

『Python １年生』　(著：森　巧尚）のP124のプログラムだと思われます。

元の表記が

```
root.geometry("200x100")
```

でした。

自分も("200x100")のx部分の入力に悩みました。
xは半角英数の小文字エックスでうまくいきました。
かけるので*にするのは駄目なようですね。